# How to fix layout management

Tags: java, image, button, layout, grid-layout

I'm doing a clone of Minesweeper in Java. Everything was fine, but I wanted to add a counter at the top. And now, some buttons are off the screen. What layouts I have to change to repair it?

Before adding counter: 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8gXP.jpg)

After adding "counter"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXJnm.jpg)

And here's my code:

```
public static JPanel generate() {
            i2w = row*row-ilosc_min;

            przyc = new Sap[row][row];      
            JPanel all = new JPanel();      //panel that contains counter and buttons
            JPanel licznik = new JPanel();  //Counter
            licznik.setBackground(Color.red);
            licznik.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MyFrame.wym-50, 50));    //counter takes 50 px height and full width of frame

            all.add(licznik);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();    //Buttons panel
            panel.setVisible(true);
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, row));                  

            for(int x = 0; x < row; x++) {  //creating buttons
                for(int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
                    Sap sp = new Sap(x, y); //My buttons that extends JButton
                    przyc[x][y] = sp;       
                    panel.add(sp);          //Adding button to panel
                }
            }
            all.add(panel);                 //All contains counter and buttons

            return all;                     //Returning it
        }
```

When I don't create a counter panel, buttons are like in the second photo.

Sorry for any mistakes, English is not my main language.

Comment: call pack() of the JFrame your Panel is in.

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/427557265655201793/569443254798385152/unknown.png) Now it's even worse.

`all.add(panel);
   Main.getFrame().pack();
   
   return all;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first do you know what was the default layout for both of your panel's ?
and the shortest work solution is to make the root panel use `BorderLayout` and when adding the counter call on your root panel object

```
add(BorderLayout.NORTH,theCounterObject);
```

and for the button's panel call this on the root panel too

```
add(BorderLayout.CENTER,theButtonsPanel);
```

this would solve it in shortened version but it's better to learn not a sip or part but all about layout managers as they are very important for swing , here is start [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

the `pack()` method is not necessary but it's a great way to fetch the perfect size it was a good idea from the comment but the problem was about your layout witch was `FlowLayout` and it's the default for panel but you should do it after changing the layout .